# Orders being sent to wrong admin email in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I set up an admin User for myself to create the site, then another for my client to use.  I changed the emails in WooCommerce to her address wherever I can find them, but the orders are still coming to me.  I don't want to remove my admin account (see: clients touching stuff). Where do I set this to make sure those orders come to her and not me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails (tab)` and On the "New Order" sub-link you'll need to add your clients email there, otherwise Woo will use the default admin email address.

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, that is showing my email as the default.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that in current version of Woo (3.4.4) those links under tabs have been replaced with a list in page body with Manage buttons beside each type of mail.

Comment: Also, if you're finding you can't change the recipient email address, there's a [bug where you can't update email info if there is an emoji in the Additional content field](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-change-email-address-for-new-orders/)